# Android: How can I place a only one list view item at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement the DrawerLayout in my sample application.

And I just take the sample NavDrawerLayout code with Image, Title, Count.
The thing is I want to place one item at the bottom of the screen.
Some people say I should use relative layout and layout_alignParentBottom set to true.

But in my MainActivity.java

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
// setting the nav drawer list adapter
adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Can you please help me?
I am newbie here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inside list view not possible. Make the element out of list view. create a layout/view and put that element (which you want at the bottom) and set gravity

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo : thank you for your message.
but is it possible with code?